# Set all array value inside loop if they are isset

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php /* for loop starts */ ?>
<div>
<input name="cat[]" type="text" />
</div>
<?php /* for loop ends */ ?>
```

I want to display each value inside the input box if their POST variable is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this bro :
i have a similar query like this.

```
<?php
    $j = 0;
    for($i = 1; $i<=8; $i++) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50% !important;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat[]" value="<?php echo isset( $_POST['cat'][$j] ) ? $_POST['cat'][$j] : ''; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php $j++; } ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure ` $_POST['PprodName'][$j]` will be available?

Comment: @ sgt BOSE no bro. it's my variable name. nut in case of waseem it will be $_POST['cat'].

Comment: @vitally first i didn't apply the for loop but when i try your code it works fine. thanks.

Comment: @Waseem Ahmed ur wlcm. but please write proper code from next time.